# Iterate over object in Jinja2?

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 on Google App Engine.  I have a ListView which renders a generic template.  At the moment, I'm not sure exactly what I want to display, so I just want to display each attribute of the model.

Is there a way to iterate over the object to output each one in a table cell?

For example:

```
{% for record in records %}
<tr>
{% for attribute in record %}
<td>{{ attribute }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick in simple python code:

```
for attribute in record.properties():
    print '%s: %s' % (attribute, getattr(record, attribute))
```

You can put the **getattr** function in the context so you can call it in jinja2 as shown below:

```
{% for record in records %}
    <tr>
    {% for attribute in record.properties() %}
        <td>{{ getattr(record, attribute) }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should not assign "getattr" to jinja context, but use the "dict like" syntax. Please check my answer above. I guess this response is not correct.

Answer (score 29):

Set `getattr` in context is a bad idea (and there is already the built-in filter [`attr`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#attr)). Jinja2 provides [dict like](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#notes-on-subscriptions) access to properties.

I guess you should do:

```
{% for record in records %}
    <tr>
    {% for attribute in record.properties() %}
        <td>{{ record[attribute] }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is better...

Comment: Even with attr ?

Comment: I ended up using loop.changed since all I needed to do was to check if it changed so I was probably over complicating my life trying to use your approach. Maybe I was just using the wrong tool, so my programming didnt work... ;)